# MongoDB Sharded, Replica'd Cluster, Query commands for all configuration / running statuses?

Tags: bash, mongodb, debugging, monitoring, diagnostics

I find that I have gotten confused on all the different commands I can use as an admin to discover what might be wrong with my MongoDB cluster. For example, running the split command, I got an error that "pre-condition failed". I found the part of the code related to its error message, 13105, https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/client/syncclusterconnection.cpp#L219 , but I'm  still confused on what I am seeing.

So I wanted to systematically check every part of my cluster. These are the commands I have run and remember right off the bat, but I'm  pretty sure I'm  forgetting some! I was never a DBA before looking at Mongo, so it would really help me to have a debugging checklist of info to get.

So my question is, have I got all the commands I need to , to get the status and configuration of each aspect of my cluster from a Mongo Console? For example, I feel sure I was able to see the sizes of each shard chunk used, but I didn't get that yet.
thank you!

Update 2014-11-22, modified the list below to include my summary findings and @wdberkeley's answer.

`//TIPS For MongoDB Debugging 
//1.Get General info on configs passed and the IP's (in Bash)
ps aux | grep -in mongo
//1A.Alternatively, to see details of configs on a single server
use admin
db.serverCmdLineOpts()
//2.Shard chunk/ranges status (from the mongoS balancer node)
sh.status()
//2A.Shard Status, verbose output
sh.status(true)
//3.Replica Set Status (from a replica set node, NOT from a mongoS)
rs.status()
//4.Mongo Server info (from anywhere; VERY LONG output)
db.serverStatus()
//5.Log summary from configured file or copy/paste of system.output into a .log file (from Bash)
mloginfo myCapturedLogs.log --distinct
//6.Diagnostic tools (from Bash)
mongostat
mongotop
//7.Check Q&A / Reference sites.`


Refs;
[6] The amazing mtools includes log parsing and log timeline visualization. https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools
[7] Q&A / Reference sites' URLS; 7A.mongo Shell Quick Reference http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/ ; 7B.StackOverflow; 7C.The stackexchange solely for dba questions, eg https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48232/mongodb-config-servers-not-in-sync  ; 8.Mongo Diagnostics FAQ http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/#faq-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh.status`, `rs.status`, and `db.serverStatus` are the main ones. Verbose output (`sh.status(true)` should list all the chunk sizes for you. There are other potentially useful functions, e.g. to see the parsed configuration options, you'd use `db.serverCmdLineOpts`. There's a [reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/) for mongo shell functions that you can look at to see if there's any more functions you're interested in. There's also some command-line tools like [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/) and [mongotop](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) that will give you useful information on the activity of your cluster.

If you post the error and how you caused it, I can try to give more specific advice on what's worth looking at for that error as well.

Comment: ty @wdberkeley! I printed all the Console commands from your reference link, that's a good idea to study them.  I added more info from my logs. For MongoTop and MongoStat, any tips on which columns/info to especially attend to? For sh.status(true) (ie verbose), I still am not seeing the disk sizes of each chunk, unless I am misreading? For example, one line is ; { "_id" : 90 } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : test-rs0 Timestamp(1, 20)

Comment: On configs in particular, I found another helpful post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232025/why-mongodb-config-servers-must-be-one-or-three-only
configuration - Why mongodb config servers must be one or three only? - Stack Overflow

Comment: I fixed the issue, and your answer was why I was able to do so easily, so I clicked solved. I printed out all the console commands and the reminder not to forget the amazing mtools https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools . I also found out there is a stackexchange solely for dba questions, eg http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48232/mongodb-config-servers-not-in-sync  Thank you again!

Comment: My details (elided from question at top); 1.The command I ran; 
mongos> db.adminCommand( { split : "testDB.testColl", middle : { _id : 75 } } ) ; 2.It returned ... "errmsg" : "exception: write $cmd failed on a node:{..."whatFailed\" : { \"ns\" : \"config.chunks\", \"q\" : { \"query\" : { \"ns\" : \"testDB.testColl\" ...."errmsg\" : \"pre-condition failed\" ; 3.and finally at the bottom its returned json says;  "code" : 13105, ..."errmsg" : "split failed"